# Simple Query - what's wrong with it?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM buildings
WHERE building_name NOT IN (SELECT building FROM employees)
```

I'm trying to answer exercise 2 with the above (try it yourself here: https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_with_nulls), but it's not returning anything. Is it a problem with the site or my query?

Thanks!

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: should that subquery be select building_name from employees? Does the employees table have a building_name column in it?

Comment: Hi @Ben, no error message, just no results (try it on the page, you'll see). The employees table has a building column that only contains a handful of the building_name from the buildings table. The goal is to find all the buildings which have no employees.

Comment: use `left join` instead of a subquery: `SELECT * FROM buildings left join employees on building_name = building 
where building is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your query, according to the question that was on the site, you can easily extract the desired data using a sub-query.

in this query first of all we get list of building name that have employees after that get list of building  not have any employees

```
select * 
from buildings 
where building_name not in (select building  
                            from employees 
                            where building not null  
                            group by building)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with null values. Thats why you have to ignore it in the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM buildings 
where building_name  not in
(select building from employees where building is not null)
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks